# Setting up Windows 10 Active Directory Lightweight

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

My basic understandings are that `Windows 10 Pro Active Directory Lightweight` can be used to create users and manage devices (Computers), its all possible without any Windows Server instance connected to Windows 10 Pro (with all updates installed and firewall turned off). Please let me know if I'm wrong.

For learning purpose I wanted to setup Active Directory on my Windows 10 Pro, after installing all related features, I created Active Directory through AD lightweight wizard, after completing the wizard I tested my connection by creating new connection in ADSI Edit and my connection was successful.

As per my understanding now it was the time to connect to `Active Directory Users and Computers` to create users, I opened `Active Directory Users and Computers` by right clicking root node I went to `Change Domain Controller` and then choose option `This domain controller or AD LDS instance` I put here ComputerName:389 (I provided this in the wizard under AD LDS partition name CN=ComputerName) in Status column it shows `Online` status but when I try to connect it says, no idea how can I solve this issue.

[Error message window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr06h.png)

**Here are the resources I was getting help from:**

http://woshub.com/install-active-directory-users-computers-aduc-console/

https://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/02/step-step-guide-setup-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-ad-lds/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/adam/binding-to-an-instance

Looks like missing part of the puzzle is domain controller, I have no idea how can I setup one without Win Server, or AD can be setup for users and devices without a domain controller? Or is it possible if I can use Free Azure Active Directory by connecting to Win 10 Pro?

I know I can use a trail version of Windows Server, but I want to keep running the AD instance for long time, as later I will be developing some C# applications and I want my sample work keep running for me for any future reference.

I'm not expert in setting up Active Directory I may use some wrong terms, please let me know if I'm wrong somewhere

Comment: Have you installed an up to date version of WINSAT tools to help you?  Microsoft Documentation on WINSAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like missing part of the puzzle is domain controller, I have no idea how can I setup one without Win Server, or AD can be setup for users and devices without a domain controller?

AD LDS is not the same thing as actual Active Directory. From my understanding, the "Lightweight" variant that you're installing is *only* the LDAP database part of AD – it has none of the other services required to make an AD "domain", e.g. there is no Kerberos KDC or Netlogon service. (Basically it's what you would get from OpenLDAP or 389DS, just a raw database that you can use for storing whatever.)

So if you want a fully functioning AD domain, you'll need either Windows Server (note that Microsoft also provides a free 180-day trial of [Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2022) and [Server 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2019) which you can run in any VM for development) **or** a Linux system with [Samba 4](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller), which can act as a Srv2008-level AD domain controller.

> and firewall turned off

No, don't get into the habit of turning off the firewall on a *domain controller.*

Comment: Or a NAS that has the option to install an Active Directory through a plugin, such as Synology or TrueNas (and probably QNAP too)